# Foundation for Apps : How to replace the default Dynamic Routing plugin?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, zurb-foundation-apps

Zurb's **Foundation For Apps** is using a [special plugin](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/angular) that creates routes directly from each view, it will parse all the HTML files to find this kind of markdown structure :

```
---
name: items
url: /items
controller: ItemCtrl
---
```

which will use to generate the necessary angular Dynamic Routing code and use **gulp** to compile a `routes.js` file which will contain this :

```
var foundationRoutes = [
    {
        "name":"items",
        "url":"/items",
        "controller":"ItemCtrl",
        "path":"templates/items.html"
    }
];
```

So my question is, if I want to change my templates path or restructre my app or if I need more advanced use for angular's **ui-router** specially **state.resolve** and **state.views**, Is there a way to replace the built-in Dynamic Routing plugin by a `$stateProvider` instance without breaking any of the other F4A's built-in components ?

---

UPDATE : The *special plugin* is called **Front Router** and this is [its Github Repository](https://github.com/zurb/front-router).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution solved my issue :

> by @escapedcat from [this github issue
>   page](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/issues/501#issuecomment-76715381) :

`gulpfile.js`: comment out the FA router part :

```
// Copies your app's page templates and generates URLs for them
gulp.task('copy-templates', ['copy'], function() {
  return gulp.src('./client/templates/**/*.html')
    // .pipe(router({ 
    //   path: 'build/assets/js/routes.js',
    //   root: 'client'
    // }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/templates'))
  ;
});
```

`index.html`: remove the `routes.js`

```
<script src="/assets/js/foundation.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="/assets/js/routes.js"></script> -->
<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
<script src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

`app.js`: comment out the dynamicRouting modules and modify the config part :

```
 angular.module('application', [
    ...
    //foundation
    'foundation',
    // 'foundation.dynamicRouting',
    // 'foundation.dynamicRouting.animations',
    ...
    ])
    .config(
      function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
          .state('yourstate', {
              url: '/yoururl',
              templateUrl: 'templates/yourTemplate.html',
              controller: 'YourController',
              resolve: {
                  // you can use resolve here, yay!
                  // promiseFooData: ['Restangular', function(Restangular) {
                  //     return Restangular.one('foo').get();
                  // }]
              }
          });
    })
  .run(run)
;
```

You need a `.state` entry for each route/template you had before.
In this example the part before looked like this :

```
---
name: yourstate
url: /yoururl
controller: YourController
---
```

---

NOTE: Animation may also be added to `state` *(after version 1.1 I guess)* :

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    animation: {
      enter: 'slideInDown',
      leave: 'fadeOut'
    }
  });
```