# Including a large project as a dependency with Webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack, zurb-foundation-apps

My particular question is with Foundation for Apps.  Webpack has been great so far if I'm working with CommonJS code or within the context of the application that I'm writing, but I'm struggling to bring in Foundation for Apps, which contains its own HTML templates, SVG icons, JavaScript, and SCSS.

I've included FfA's JavaScript by requiring the concatenated source (which isn't ideal but it works).  I can also include SCSS in a more clean way since Webpack's sass loader seems to know what to do with `@import` statements.

The key problems arise when FfA's source (Angular) requests HTML from a path that doesn't exist post-Webpack.

For example, a request will be made to get `/components/modal/modal.html` but the only thing in my public directory is `bundle.js`.  How can I load all of the HTML templates and replace any occurrences of `templateUrl` paths in FfA's source with `require` statements that resolve to the path of the loaded HTML?  Am I going down the right path or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

F4A is using the built-in [Front Router](https://github.com/zurb/front-router) plugin which simplifies the creation of routes in AngularJS by allowing you to define them directly in your view templates. As shown [here](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/issues/387#issuecomment-70080161) it is meant to be used in the most basic sense and for rapid prototyping. For example, even if it implements Angular's **UI-Router** and its `states`, you can't use their **resolve** property.

I'm not familiar with **Webpack** and at which level it generates the required *templates* but if you can't generate them as [Front Router](https://github.com/zurb/front-router)'s expected markdowns before being generated by `gulp`, then you may disable the plugin and implement your custom `$stateProvider` instance by leaving F4A out of it and solve it within AngularJs :

```js
.state('yourstate', {
    url: '/yoururl',
    templateUrl: 'templates/yourTemplate.html',
    //
    // or maybe something like :
    //    -- this is guessing. i'm not familiar with webpack :) --
    //
    // templateUrl: function (wabpack) {
    //     return '/partials/' +  wabpack.path + '.html';
    // }
    //
    controller: 'YourController',
    resolve: {
        // you may also use resolve here for extra logic before
        // loading your template
    }
```

About how to disable *F4A Front Rooter* and how to implement your own `$stateProvider` instance you may check this :

[Foundation for Apps : How to replace the default Dynamic Routing plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788600/foundation-for-apps-how-to-replace-the-default-dynamic-routing-plugin)