# Multiple views on a single template @ Foundation-Apps? (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, view, zurb-foundation-apps

How can I load multiple views on a single template?

For example I have my main page splitted in 2 columns and I want to add a view on the left column and another, different view on the right column.

What code do I need to put in which files in order to acomplish this? I want to mention that I know how to add a single view per template. Be that as it may I'm still learning.

I've read this -- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views -- but I can't seem to optimize that with Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

As said by one of its creators [here](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/issues/387#issuecomment-68867665) :

> the dynamic routing in FA is meant to be used in the most basic sense
>   and for rapid prototyping. More advanced features should be left to a
>   more conventional routing built out the angular way.

So you won't be able to use `.state.views` within its default [Front Router](https://github.com/zurb/front-router) which was built to simplify the use of the framework for non angularJs developers. To achieve what you need I recommend disabling it and implement your own `$stateProvider` instance.

More details about how to do it may be found here :

[Foundation for Apps : How to replace the default Dynamic Routing plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788600/foundation-for-apps-how-to-replace-the-default-dynamic-routing-plugin)