# AngularJS/Foundation for Apps - Can't use controller in partial

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, zurb-foundation, controllers

I've got a basic web app I'm making using Foundation for Apps. My index.html contains a template, home.html in /templates/, which contains a small partial, status.html in /partials/.  (it's for a dog treat dispenser using a Particle Photon)

I can use custom controllers just fine in any of my templates, but not in my partials. Here's the relevant code I'm using (redacts replaced with "...":

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="application">
  <head>
    ...    
  </head>
  <body>
      ...
      <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**home.html**

```
---
name: home
url: /
---

<div class="grid-block align-center">
    <center>
        <br>
        <div ng-include="'/partials/status.html'"></div>
        <p ng-controller="variableCtrl">Food last given: {{last}}</p>  
...
```

**status.html**

```
<p ng-controller="statusCtrl">Status: {{status}} | <span id="activity">{{activity}}</span></p>
```

**app.js**

```
.factory('variableService', ['$http', function($http) { 
    var accessToken = "...";
    var device_ID = "...";
    var apiURL = "https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/" + device_ID + "/";

    var getVariable = function(getVar) {
        return $http.get(apiURL+  getVar + '?access_token=' + accessToken).then(function (data) {
        return data.data.result;    // this becomes the fulfilled value of the promise
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('An error occurred while getting variable:', err);
        throw err;                  // rethrow error so it will propagate
    });
    };

    return {
        getVariable: getVariable,
        accessToken: accessToken,
        device_ID: device_ID
    };
}])
.controller('variableCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'variableService', '$http', function($scope, $state, variableService, $http) {
    moment().format("hh:mm:ss");

    $scope.last = variableService.getVariable("last").then(function (result) {
        if (moment.unix(result).fromNow() === "Invalid date") {
            $scope.last = "?";
        } else {
            $scope.last = moment.unix(result).fromNow();
        };
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('An error occurred while getting variable:', err);
    });

    $scope.treatSize = variableService.getVariable("treatSize").then(function (result) {
        $scope.treatSize = result;
        console.log(result);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('An error occurred while getting variable:', err);
    });

    $scope.mealSize = variableService.getVariable("mealSize").then(function (result) {
        $scope.mealSize = result;
        console.log(result);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log('An error occurred while getting variable:', err);
    });
  }])

  .controller('statusCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'variableService', '$http', function($scope, $state, variableService, $http) {
    var source = new EventSource("https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/"+variableService.device_ID+"/events/?access_token="+variableService.accessToken);
    source.addEventListener("status", function(event) {
        event = JSON.parse(event.data);
        $scope.status = event.data;
        console.log($scope.status);
    });
    source.addEventListener("activity", function(event) {
        event = JSON.parse(event.data);
        $scope.activity = event.data;
        console.log($scope.activity);
    });
  }])
```

I'd imagine maybe I need to create my own directive or scope is wrong or something, but I can't get it to work. I can see in the console that it's receiving data, but they won't populate in my bindings. I'm new to Angular and still fairly new to javascript and webdev in general, so I'm sure I'm missing something stupid.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: For clarity, I'm having difficulty getting {{status}} and {{activity}} to display

**SOLVED**: The problem with this wasn't really scopes, states, or views. For the `addEventListener`s, I needed to add `$scope.$apply();` to the end of each function and it updated the data binds as it should. Everything works just fine with that simple change.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Try assigning the controller to your template from a stateProvider

Comment: I tried implementing this with Foundation using this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788600/foundation-for-apps-how-to-replace-the-default-dynamic-routing-plugin

but then none of my templates would load at all.

So for additional troubleshooting, I changed the home.html controller to `statusCtrl` and added `{{status}}` and `{{activity}}` directly to the home.html and it isn't populating those at all. Any idea why?

Comment: Edit: Solved this issue by adding `$scope.$apply();` to the end of each eventListener. Checking to see if this all works with partial now...

Comment: Yep, the problem was adding `$scope.$apply();`. Nothing else